# RegExKitLite matching HTML tags and extracting text

Tags: macos, regexkitlite

how uo use RegExKitLite matching HTML tags and extracting text ?
ie:

```
<li color=red>
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
</li>
```

how to get content between `<li>   </li>` ?

Answer (score 2):

It's generally considered bad form to use regexp to parse HTML - have you considered using a XML/HTML parsing library?
See here: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)